# Java ProcessBuilder is not executing command but also doesn't return an error

Tags: java, processbuilder, oggvorbis

Running the following code works fine on my pc but doesn't when run by nginx-clojure on my server.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/vorbiscomment", "-w", "-t", "\"title=MySong\"", "-t", "\"artist=SomeArtist\"", "\"/media/music/SomeArtist/MySong.ogg\"");
```

Background:

I am working on a REST API for a music related project. It's using an nginx module (nginx-clojure) for embedding Java programs. My aim right now is to edit vorbis-tags utilising the unix commandline utility *vorbiscomment* and Java ProcessBuilder. The code does work on my pc, which makes me believe that it might have something to do with permissions on the server. My problem is that I'm not getting any output from the ProcessBuilder indicating that the command failed. I tried:

```
Process proc = pb.start();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    sb.append(line).append('\n');
}
return sb.toString();
```

which didn't output anything.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Remove the double quote characters from your arguments.  It’s `"artist=SomeArtist"`.  Encasing it in double quotes is needed for a shell, not for direct execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading from the `Process`'s InputStream. You should be looking at 
`Process.getErrorStream()` or `Process.getOutputStream()`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

You could also inspect the [exitValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue()) to see if the process successfully completed.

Comment: While it is possible to examine the InputStream and ErrorrStream directly, it’s usually easier to leave them alone and call [pb.inheritIO()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO%28%29) instead, to make them show up in the Java process’s standard output/error.

Comment: `Process.getInputStream` is stdout from the process (input to java) and in general reading it is correct, while `.getOutputStream` is stdin to the process _from_ java. But adding `.getErrorStream` which is stderr from the process is indeed probably the answer. I'd vote +.5 if Stack allowed that.